# Calculate Average of Each Series of Numbers From Text File

Tags: arrays, loops, visual-studio-2012, series, basic

Currently, the code I have pulls the data from the txt file and places the list of numbers into a list box. I now need to edit the program to calculate the average of each series of numbers, with each series being separated by a 0. I need to store the data into an array and loop through it to preform the calculations, but I am unsure how to separate each series of numbers to get the average of each series, not just the average of the entire data set.

This is the list of numbers I have:
10
15
20
20
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
0
10
20
30
40
50
60
0
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
0
5
8
9
5
3
80
2
23
65
0

And this is the code I have that currently just pulls the data from the file and places it as is into the list box:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim strData As String

Private Sub ReadButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ReadButton.Click
    Dim strReader As System.IO.StreamReader

    Try
        strReader = New System.IO.StreamReader("NumberData.txt")
        strData = strReader.ReadLine
        Do While Not strReader.EndOfStream
            DataListBox.Items.Add(strData)
            strData = strReader.ReadLine
        Loop
        DataListBox.Items.Add(strData)
        strReader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        DataListBox.Items.Add(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

I appreciate the help, I have been programming so much lately that my brain just can't seem to figure this one out on it's own!

Answer (score 0):

No array needed; just use 2 variables: one that's incremented for each item read, and one to hold the sum so far.  As you read each value, first check to see if it's zero; if it is, then calculate mean by dividing the sum by the count, and do whatever with it (and then clear your two tracking vars); if it's not, then go ahead and add it in for the next sum.   (If you don't have a trailing 0, then you'll have to force an extra calc on the last series.)